# How to get the best LINPACK result and conquer the Top500?

Tags: optimization, benchmark, hpc

Given a large **Linux HPC cluster** with hundreds/thousands of nodes. What are **your best practices** to get the best possible [LINPACK benchmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK) ([HPL](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/)) result to [submit](http://www.top500.org/project/call_for_participation)  for the [Top500 supercomputer list](http://www.top500.org/lists)?

To give you an idea what kind of answers I would appreciate here are some sub-questions (with links):

- How to you [tune the parameters](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/tuning.html) (`N`, `NB`, `P`, `Q`, memory-alignment, etc) for the `HPL.dat` file (without spending too much time trying each possible permutation - esp with large problem sizes N)?
- Are there any [Top500](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOP500) **submission rules** to be aware of? What is allowed, what isn't?
- Which [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) product, which version? Does it make a difference?
- Any special **host order** in your MPI machine file?
- Do you use **CPU pinning**?
- How to you configure your **interconnect**? Which interconnect?
- Which [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) package do you use for which CPU model? ([Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl/), [AMD ACML](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/libraries/acml/pages/default.aspx), [GotoBLAS2](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2/), etc.)
- How do you **prepare for the big run** (on all nodes)? Start with small runs on a subset of nodes and then scale up? Is it really necessary to run LINPACK with a **big run on all of the nodes** (or is extrapolation allowed)?
- How do you optimize for the latest Intel/AMD CPUs? [Hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)? [NUMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access)?
- Is it worth it to **recompile the software stack** or do you use [precompiled binaries](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-linpack-download/)? Which settings?
  Which **compiler** optimizations, which compiler? (What about profile-based compilation?)
- How to get the best result given only a **limited amount of time** to do the benchmark run? (You can block a huge cluster forever)
- How do you **prepare the individual nodes** (stopping system daemons, freeing memory, etc)?
- How do you deal with **hardware faults** (ruining a huge run)?
- Are there any **must-read documents or websites** about this topic? E.g. I would love to hear about some  **background stories** of some of the current Top500 systems and how they did their LINPACK benchmark.

I deliberately *don't* want to mention concrete hardware details or discuss hardware recommendations because I don't want to limit the answers. However, feel free to mention hints e.g. for specific CPU models.

Answer (score 1):

Give this tool a try it might help you, it suggests tuned values for some of the critical HPL parameters and there's a step by step howto for running HPL on clusters. The tool also estimates your rank in the TOP500 list depending on your system specs:

http://hpl-calculator.sourceforge.net

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: There's a similar tool from Advanced Clustering:

http://www.advancedclustering.com/faq/how-do-i-tune-my-hpldat-file.html